# Caching dynamic SVG Image with React

Tags: reactjs, svg, semantic-ui

I want to be able to load multiple large and heavy SVG files (~2 MB per SVG when all referenced images/resources are counted) which the user can interact with and manipulate, and be able to swap between them. The idea being that only one SVG can be seen at a time, but I want the state of each to be saved/kept when swapping out. At this point I'm playing around with React to understand its capabilities/limitations with my use case, and so far I just have a React UI with no supporting back-end capabilities in play.

I'm using Semantic-UI tabs to manage the swapping of the SVGs (each tab contains a different SVG) and hooks are placed onto the SVG to allow the user interact with it and through this interaction change it (i.e.: click a shape to change its fill color). Everything works perfectly fine while the SVG is on screen (register click, update SVG, scroll to zoom, click+drag to pan), however all changes are lost as soon as I switch to a different tab.

For example: if the user zooms, pans, and clicks a shape to change its color, the SVG updates as expected. Switch to a different tab, the SVG on the other tab is displayed. Switch back to the previous tab, and while the SVG reappears, but it's in its default (original) state with all zoom/pan/colors reset.

Based on what I'm seeing, it would appear that the SVG is lost/destroyed when the tab containing it is deselected, forcing it to be re-created when switching back (and thus it comes back in its default/original state). I can easily imagine a solution where the state is saved to the server with each manipulation and then retrieved and applied when returning to the SVG. My concern is more so with the destruction/recreation of the SVG when switching from/to its tab. Is there a way to cache the modified SVG such that the modified image is shown rather than the default one? Given how large my SVGs are, how long they will most likely take to load, and the sheer volume of changes that may need to be applied when recreating the image I can very easily see the process of recreating the image taking so long as to make the overall application unusable.

Other options I've considered:

- Server Side Components - from what I understand, these are non-interactive so the would be no way to handle click events from the user (I want to be able to listen for when elements within the SVG are clicked)
- Server Side Rendering - I believe that this could help with speed up the creation/load of the SVG, but it won't prevent the need for recreating/rerendering the image, just have it appear in its expected state right away
- Merging all SVGs into a single super SVG - only option I can think of being truly viable, where each currently separate SVG becomes a child of the "super SVG" and only the one desired "child SVG" is displayed to the user at a time. Thus negating the need to destroy/create the image when swapping.

For context, I'm looking at migrating from a Java Swing based application, where Apache Batik is used to render the SVG to a Swing Canvas and the swapping is handled by simply showing the desired Canvas while hiding the others. Since the hidden Canvas's remain in the overall Swing hierarchy they are not destroyed and remained cached until the whole application is terminated.